# Wildcard subdomain redirect using mod_rewrite

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to figure out how to do a redirect using mod_rewrite to a new domain, that will include a wildcard subdomain redirection.

I am hoping for such result:

```
domain1.com                      -> domain2.com
domain1.com/foo/bar?baz=quux     -> domain2.com/foo/bar?baz=quux
www.domain1.com                  -> www.domain2.com
www.domain1.com/foo/bar?baz=quux -> www.domain2.com/foo/bar?baz=quux
sub.domain1.com                  -> sub.domain2.com
sub.domain1.com/foo/bar?baz=quux -> sub.domain2.com/foo/bar?baz=quux
*.domain1.com                    -> *.domain2.com
*.domain1.com/foo/bar?baz=quux   -> *.domain2.com/foo/bar?baz=quux
```

I was trying something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+\.)?domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the `%1` which I was hoping to refer to the optional subdomain caught in the `RewriteCond` is not brought through to is completely dropped, so any requests ends up being redirected to `http://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible you're falling through and catching another RewriteCond elsewhere? It looks to me like the RewriteCond in your example will never match an HTTP_HOST that ends in domain1.com due to the presence of the `!` negation prefix.

This slight modification seems to work the way you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```